# Как правильно проводить классификацию

Tags: python, data-mining

Здравствуйте дорогие знатоки машинного обучения, я столкнулся с такой проблеммой, у меня есть выборка пациентов и мне надо  на основе их истории болезни  классфицировать этих пациентов   на 2 класса: на пациентов с инсультом и пациентов без инсульта. Дело в том что я не знаю по каким параметрам проводить классификацию  , у некоторых пациентов один набор параметорв а у других другой набор параметров, как в таких случаях поступают?

Comment: Есть ли параметры, которые есть у каждого пациента, по которым можно определить инсульт?

Comment: в этом то и дело что нет  Алексей Воронов, некоторые параметры могут сопадать , но чтобы у всех пациентов был хотя бы один совпадающий параметр такого не наблюдается

Comment: Ваша задача интересна. На данный момент в рамках кандидатской диссертации я занимаюсь разработкой нейрочипа и изучением машинного обучения. Если у Вас есть желание, то я могу подключиться к решению вашей задачи.  Я как раз искал себе какую нибудь задачу для решения которой необходимо машинное обучение. aleksey.voronov.36@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать поступить следующим образом.
Если не все параметры несут необходимую для нас информацию, тогда можно сначала провести предварительную классификацию на нужные и не нужные параметры. Если же все параметры нам необходимы, то такого делать не надо.

Далее можно провести классификацию параметров по их направленности (не могу подобрать правильное определение, так как не селен в медицине), а так же по их значимости. Возможно какие то параметры являются 100% показателем инсульта, а какие то могут дать верный результат только в совокупности с другими параметрами.

Далее полученный(обработанный и классифицированный) массив данных использовать для обучения нейронной сети.

Так же для предварительной классификации можно использовать предварительно обученную нейронную сеть.

Есть очень хорошая книга: "Python и машинное обучение. Себастьян Рашка"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]